# alternating current through an inductor

Tags: inductance

In alternating current through an inductor, why the voltage across the inductor provided by the a.c power supply must be equal to the back emf to maintain the current in the inductor?

Comment: What do you mean by "emf"? I don't understand your question. Could you please describe in more detail?

Comment: sorry. back-e.m.f. (electromotive force).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is simple. If the system should maintain a certain current and there appears an electromotive force, that would reduce the current according to the induced negative voltage. Only if the voltage is compensated by the reverse voltage from the power supply will the current stay constant.